# SAS - How to pass libname as parameter to macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Say, I have a SAS macro like the following:

```
%macro someMacro (something=);
    libname mylib "some/path/that/is/awesome";
%mend;
```

How can I get rid of the string literal `"some/path/that/is/awesome"` and instead pass it as a parameter to the macro?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special about libname string literals, they're just strings, so you just put the parameter inside the double quotations (or you can include the quotations in the macro parameter, but that's not usually considered a best practice).

```
%macro someMacro(something=, libparam=);
  libname mylib "&libparam.";
%mend someMacro;
```